# Initializer list weirdly depends on order of parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, initializer-list, type-traits

I have the following snippet of code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

template <typename F, typename... FIn>
auto min_on(F f, const FIn&... v) -> typename std::common_type<FIn...>::type
{
  using rettype = typename std::common_type<FIn...>::type;
  rettype result = std::numeric_limits<rettype>::max();
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{((f(v) < result) ? (result = static_cast<rettype>(v), 0) : 0)...};
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  auto mod2 = [](int a)
  {
    return a % 2;
  };

  assert(min_on(mod2, 2) == 2);     // PASSES as it should
  assert(min_on(mod2, 3) == 3);     // PASSES as it should
  assert(min_on(mod2, 2, 3) == 3);  // PASSES but shouldn't - should be 2
  assert(min_on(mod2, 2, 3) == 2);  // FAILS but shouldn't - should be 2
}
```

The idea behind template function `min_on` is that it should return the parameter `x` from list of parameters passed to it `v` so that it gives the smallest values for expression `f(v)`.

The problem that I have observed is that somehow the order of parameters inside the [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is important so the the code above will fail whereas this code:

```
  assert(min_on(mod2, 3, 2) == 2);
```

will work. What might be wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function sets `result` to `v` if `f(v) < result`. With `mod2` as `f`, `f(v)` will only ever result in a 0, 1 or a -1. Which means that if all of your values are greater than 1, `result` will be set to the last `v` which was tested, because `f(v)` will always be less than `result`. Try putting a negative number in the middle of a bunch of positive numbers, and the negative number will always be the result, no matter where you place it.

```
assert(min_on(mod2, 2, 3, 4, -3, 7, 6, 5) == -3);
```

Perhaps you want this instead:

```
std::initializer_list<int>{((f(v) < f(result)) ? (result = static_cast<rettype>(v), 0) : 0)...};
```

The difference is I am testing `f(v) < f(result)`, instead of `f(v) < result`. Although, the function is still not correct generally because it assumes that `f(std::numeric_limits<rettype>::max())` is the max possible value. In the case of `mod2` it works. But with something like this:

```
[](int a) { return -a; }
```

it would clearly be wrong. So perhaps you could instead require a first argument:

```
template <typename F, typename FirstT, typename... FIn>
auto min_on(F f, const FirstT& first, const FIn&... v)
    -> typename std::common_type<FirstT, FIn...>::type
{
  using rettype = typename std::common_type<FirstT, FIn...>::type;
  rettype result = first;
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{((f(v) < f(result)) ? (result = static_cast<rettype>(v), 0) : 0)...};
  return result;
}
```

Or, if you're want to avoid unnecessary calls to `f`:

```
template <typename F, typename FirstT, typename... FIn>
auto min_on(F f, const FirstT& first, const FIn&... v)
    -> typename std::common_type<FirstT, FIn...>::type
{
  using rettype = typename std::common_type<FirstT, FIn...>::type;
  rettype result = first;
  auto result_trans = f(result);
  auto v_trans = result_trans;
  (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(
    (v_trans = f(v), v_trans < result_trans)
        ? (result = static_cast<rettype>(v), result_trans = v_trans, 0) : 0)...};
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Would be more efficient to store both best input and best output though, to avoid repeated calls to f.

Comment: Perfect answer! I couldn't ask for more.Thanks a lot Benjamin

Comment: This should return an optional, or fail on the empty list.  Your suggestion fails on empty at compile time, which is good.  Note you can at modedt cost avoid copying the result type repeatedly (could be expensive!) by keeping track of the answer's index and switching back to the value after finding the answer, but that is pretty advanced.